# Amazon S3 Static Hosting Custom Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm learning some web development and am using Amazon S3 as a web host with a custom domain from Google domains. I used the guides from the Amazon AWS page and was able to set up the web page but I have a problem with getting the custom domain to work.

For example, Amazon S3 has the endpoint URL to www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com and I want my domain example.com to show up. When I load the page for www.example.com, it loads the page however it still shows the example.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com when I want it to show the simple example.com instead.

From what I can tell, I need a CNAME, I've set it up as www.example.com -> www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com with permanent redirect (301) and forward path.

Please help!

Comment: Check the setup on the www bucket.  "Redirect all requests to another hostname" should say "example.com" -- not the endpoint for the example.com bucket.

Comment: Did you follow the directions on [Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)? Specifically, is your **bucket name** set to your domain name?

Comment: @John Rotenstein Yes that is what I followed, I have www.example.com and example.com as a bucket as well. I don't have any Route 53 set up though, and I'm not sure if it's required in this case?

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot I have changed my www bucket to now redirect all requests to example.com instead of the endpoint. I'm not sure if it will be of any help, but the site in question is khatri.cc

Comment: It looks like you are using S3 behind Cloudflare.  The site seems to be working correctly.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Yes it seems to be working properly now through Cloudflare, I also wanted to know how to stop latency when changing files on the website to go live on the site itself, the Amazon S3 link shows the changes instantly while through the DNS on Cloudflare it has a delay (it seems I can fix it through clearing the cache on Cloudflare though) but there must be another method?

Comment: That's really a different question, and probably one that's already been answered here.  Setting `Cache-Control:` on the objects in S3 to appropriate values for your purposes should prevent Cloudflare from caching them longer than the specified value.  For example, `Cache-Control: public, max-age=30` should trigger Cloudflare to consult S3 to see if the object has changed, rather than serve up a copy from cache, if the cached version is over 30 seconds old when the next request is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone was wondering how I got it to work, I ended up using Cloudflare with its free DNS options. I added the DNS servers to google domains and then added two CNAMES:

```
@ -> example.com -> example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (for the root)

CNAME -> www -> www.example.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (for the www redirect)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Google side, configure the CNAME record (**www**) to point to **s3.amazonaws.com.** (yes, the dot included) ... like this:

[image]

... and wait a few minutes.

Make sure your S3 bucket is named: **www.yourdomain.com**