# "This site can’t be reached" error - AWS s3+route53 and godaddy domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cross-domain, amazon-route53

I did everything by youtube guides, but still, I have a problem uploading my website.

1. I've created a bucket with s3, uploaded the files and I actually can see the website in this domain:
   http://www.howtoripen.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/
2. This is route 53:
   https://i.imagesup.co/images2/a75abb236b7db2b6edb018b59e31a8ce4362b3ec.png
3. I purchased the domain in GoDaddy "howtoripen.com".
   https://i.imagesup.co/images2/0e4f8469a0cc2ffd016f36f4cc678f1391d10957.png
   I copied ns-150.awsdns-18.com and org to GoDaddy domain severs, But still when I write in the url "www.howtoripen.com". I have this error:
   This site can’t be reachedhowtoripen.com’s server IP address could not be found.

I really don't understand too much when it comes to this stuff, THANK FOR YOU HELP ! :)

Comment: You need an A record, did you define that?

Comment: @Behe Do you mean in the route 53 ? I think I did it - I wrote "www.howtoripen.com". You can see the result in the second link i have posted.

Comment: That's why I am asking, I can see no A record there.

Comment: @Behe So how can I do it ? create record set > name: add "www" > alias: yes > alias: s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com (Tha't the automatic suggestion). > click create ? Still not working.

Comment: @Behe https://i.imagesup.co/images2/39bc4fff59e7da1604d10c6458fff900ada80112.png and I don't know if it's a matter the name of the bucket is www.howtoripen.com

Comment: Duplicate  [Connect AWS s3 bucket and route 53 to godaddy domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58892395/connect-aws-s3-bucket-and-route-53-to-godaddy-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Make sure your S3 bucket is named: www.yourdomain.com
- Configure your bucket for website hosting
- Configure the CNAME record (www) to point to s3.amazonaws.com. (yes,
  the dot included) Take a look at this answer: 
  [Amazon S3 Static Hosting Custom Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516924/amazon-s3-static-hosting-custom-domain/50571556#50571556)