# Connect AWS s3 bucket and route 53 to godaddy domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cross-domain, amazon-route53

I bought this domain with GoDaddy: "howtoripen.com".

When I put in URL "howtoripen.com" it loads me GoDaddy LandPage:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/bd5fc5bb955d4442c9d17bff3b05a79834a88490.png

I have created a bucket in s3 and configured things in route 53:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/5d0e25f69be70a468be4e0085404c81d102e0715.png

And I can't see my HTML, CSS and js files that I uploaded to the bucket. When I click on endpoint URL everything seems fine: http://howtoripen.com.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/

** I have copied the ns-47.awsdns-05.com and org to godaddy DNS servernames.

What can be the problem ? How can I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: `howtoripen.com has address 50.63.202.62` & `62.202.63.50.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ip-50-63-202-62.ip.secureserver.net.` And your name servers are showing as; `NS47.DOMAINCONTROL.COM` & `NS48.DOMAINCONTROL.COM`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you had configured the DNS settings correctly, It might take upto 48 hrs to reflect.